# Simple algorithm to generate a Mondrian "Random Grid"

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, approximation-theory

I was wondering if there is a simple way or algorithm that can generate 2-d grids resembling Mondrian paintings like the boogie woogie grid ( https://nuit-blanche.blogspot.com/2010/12/cs-boogie-woogie-grid.html ) or similar grid (https://www.google.com/images?q=mondrian)

Thanks in advance,

Igor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one algorithmification (if I may coin a word!) of Mondrian paintings, by
Tom Gedeon, "[Neural Network for Modeling Esthetic Selection](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-69162-4_69),"
*Neural Information Processing*,
Springer *Lecture Notes in Computer Science*, 2008, Volume 4985/2008, 666-674.
From the Abstract:

> Our domain is the automatic generation of Mondrian-like images with an interactive interface for the user to select images.

Here is one of the figures from the paper:

[image: Mondrian]

(The Springer link needs an access subscription. Here is [a Google books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=noYjY8rMilEC&pg=PA666&lpg=PA666&dq=Neural+Network+for+Modeling+Esthetic+Selection&source=bl&ots=O2Cqm0Y9mn&sig=0-43_0d9sGR4_Pc07sW4weXkwEY&hl=en&ei=hcUgTdzyBIKclgfHoNDpCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&sqi=2#v=onepage&q=Neural%20Network%20for%20Modeling%20Esthetic%20Selection&f=false).)
Gedeon cites an analysis of Mondrian paintings by the physicist [Richard Taylor](https://web.archive.org/web/20120617142742/http://pages.uoregon.edu/msiuo/taylor/art/fractal_taylor.html):
"Fractal Expressionism - Where Art Meets Science," *Art And Complexity*, Ed. J. Casti and A. Karlqvist, Elsevier Science, Amsterdam (2003).

Here is a second: "[The Mondrian Process](https://www.academia.edu/245350/The_Mondrian_Process)" by Daniel Roy and Yee Teh,
*Adv. in Neural Inform. Processing Syst*, 21, p.27, 2009.  From the Abstract:

> We describe a novel class of distributions, which we call Mondrian processes, which can be interpreted as probability distributions over $k$d-tree data structures.

Here is their first figure:

[image: kd-tree]